# To find customer's first login

Tags: magento

Magento 1.6.

Within the login processing code, is it possible to find out when the user/customer has logged in for the very first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Magento is configured **not** to use double-opt-in (email confirmation) for customer registrations, then you can use what @PauGNU already posted:

```
$created_at = $customer->getCreatedAt();
```

But when it comes to double-opt-in, Magento creates the customer account *immediately*, i.e. setting `created_at` to the current system time, but does not activate it (so that customer cannot login before confirming) and only sends a confirmation mail.

This means an unkown delay (minutes, days, weeks, whatever) between `created_at` and the very first login, so `created_at` wouldn't be of use anymore.

Actually, Magento *has* a place, where customer login times are being tracked by default: the table field `log_customer.login_at`, accessible by `Mage_Log_Model_Customer`, for example.

But, if you plan to use it:

- by default the class has no method to get the very first login. You'd need to develop that yourself.
- if "Log Cleaning" is active (to keep the database smaller), you'll gonna lose the saved login times.

In that case, I'd prefer identifying the most proper event, hooking into it and saving only the very first login time per customer to a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the first login is always when the customer registers itself in the web, you only need to check out the field «created_at» on the customer_entity table.

If you load a customer, it's really easy to get that data:

```
$created_at = $customer->getCreatedAt();
```

Comment: This is only true for sites which do not require administrative approval. To preserve the "first login" data in perpetuity for all cases would require a module which could implement a new datetime attribute + observer to populate this attribute in `customer_customer_authenticated` event.